# Executing Random in Android App

Tags: java, android, random

I am currently a beginner in **Android Development** and I need to display a random
string on the user's screen.

I have already made an array and got a random string from it,

So how do I display this string on the user's screen? Sorry, I am only a beginner and can't find this anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Display the string where? With a toast? In a Textview? You will need to provide some more info.

Comment: In a text view, yes.

Comment: please post some code and or some more things you may have tried so it is easier to help you. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a TextView in your activity's layout:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"/>
```

Then in your activity's `onCreate` method fetch it and change its text to your string:

```
String myString = "abc";
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText(myString);
```

If this doesn't make any sense at all, then you should try reading this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a `TextView`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html